# How do I make Linux use a screen connected to its second display port (VGA) instead of its first (DVI) for console?

Tags: linux, graphics-card, vga, console, dvi

My computer has a graphics card with a DVI port (port 1) and a VGA port (port 2).  How can I make the console on Linux display on port 2 instead of port 1?  During POST, everything is mirrored on both displays, but as soon as I get to the login: prompt it only outputs on port 1.  Yeah, I could probably buy a DVI->VGA adapter, but this seems like something that can be set, maybe in kernel boot params.